# Errors Submitting Updated Version to Transferred iOS app

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, code-signing, application-loader

I get a lot of apps from 3rd party vendors. I re-sign them, upload them with Application Loader and all is good.

Until now. This one vendor wanted to create the app on iTunes Connect, then transfer ownership of the app. Sure. I'll try it. The transfer went fine and everything is good.

Now it comes time to update the app. I get the binary, I re-sign it and push it up. I get this error.

[image: Error Message]

I login to iTunes Connect and check out the app. It has the original team identifier from the vendor. Not the one from my company/account. So I can't sign the app. If I don't sign the app, but just submit it signed from the vendor it uploads, gets stuck in processing for a few days, then vanishes.

So anyone know what I need to do to submit an update properly?

Answer (score 0):

You got the `ERROR ITMS-90046` to become compatible and submit your app.

Go to `Images.xcassets` add in `LaunchImage` the following splash files size:

```
- 640x960 
- 640X1136 
- 768x1024
- 1536x2048
```

Sample:

[image: splash images]

After that, build and archive your new `.ipa` file and submit normally.

Answer (score -1):

1.clean project.
2.restart xcode.
3.archives and upload again.

work for me.

Comment: For this process Xcode is not used. The vendor hands me the .ipa or .xcarchive and I use codesign to sign it then upload it using Application Loader.